# MySQL - Foreign Key Problem

Tags: mysql, foreign-key

I'm trying to get to grips with Foreign Keys in MySQL (5.6), and can't figure out why the below doesn't work:

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`parenttable` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `ix_parent_name` (`parent_name` ASC));

CREATE TABLE `test`.`childtable` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `ix_parent_id` (`parent_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_parent`
    FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`)
    REFERENCES `test`.`parenttable` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

The warning I get from `SHOW WARNINGS;` is:

```
Create table 'test/childtable' with foreign key constraint failed. There is no index in the referenced table where the referenced columns appear as the first columns.
```

But as far as I can see the 'referenced table' is `test.parenttable`

The 'referenced column' is `id`, and `id` is the `Primary Key` so automatically has a `UNIQUE` index, right?

I checked the documentation, and as far as I can see I meet all the criteria:

- Same Storage Engine: INNODB by default
- Similar Data Types: both are INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
- Indexes on both Foreign and referenced keys

What am I missing?

Comment: `childtable.parent_id` is not `UNSIGNED`.

Comment: cheers. I thought it would be something simple (but not that simple). Problem is it doesn't work on my live DB (test DB is fine) I get: `Error Code: 1022. Can't write; duplicate key in table 'childtable'` - further investigation required I think. Cheers

Comment: problem fixed - I had an old table in the database that also had fk_parent defined. Changing it to fk_parent_new fixed the problem.